# SQL: Finding Quantiles Across Columns

Tags: sql, hive

Here's an easy one. I have a sales table that looks like this:

```
store_id   industry_code   sales_person_1  sales_person_2  ... sales_person_n
       1            1000            20.75           15.50  ...            100
       2            2000            15.54           16.84  ...            125
```

Suppose I want to find out which quantile sales_person_2 falls into for `store_id=1`. I know I can use a window function `ntile(5) OVER(PARTITION BY ____ ORDER BY SUM(__) DESC)` to divide a column into 5 buckets and use that to identify which bucket an arbitrary value falls into. What's the best way to do that *across* columns rather than within a column?

Comment: There isn't a good way.  The best approach is to store the data with values in separate rows rather than in columns.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is `explode` your columns into several rows:

```
select t.store_id, 
       t.industry_code, 
       s.val
  from test_table t
  lateral view explode(array(sales_person_1, sales_person_2, ..., sales_person_n)) s as val
```

and only then use `ntile`.

See [the example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView#LanguageManualLateralView-Example) from the Hive docs.